The batch insert is not being applied in PostgreSQL
I want to apply batch insertion using PostgreSQL, but even after searching online, I couldn't easily solve it. Currently, I'm using spring-boot 3.3.0v and PostgreSQL 16. Could you help me figure out what might be the issue?
I haven't been able to sleep for days because of this issue. Please help me.
( Even more interestingly, when I configure it to use MySQL, batch inserts work fine.)
Here's my application.yml configuration:
spring:
  jpa:
    show_sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        generate_statistics : true
        order_inserts: true
        order_updates: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 10
          batch_versioned_data: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/batch?rewriteBatchedInserts=true
    username: postgres
    password: 
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
#    hikari:
#      data-source-properties:
#        rewriteBatchedInserts: true

Below are the basic objects and business logic:
@Entity
@Getter
@Table(name = "bacnet")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BacnetEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    private int deviceId;

    private int objectType;

    private int objectId;

    public BacnetEntity(int deviceId, int objectType, int objectId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.objectType = objectType;
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }
}


    @Transactional
    void run() {
        List<BacnetEntity> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            BacnetEntity bacnetEntity = new BacnetEntity(i, i, i);
            list.add(bacnetEntity);
        }
        bacnetRepository.saveAll(list);
    }

2024-06-08T23:26:59.923+09:00  INFO 28496 --- [           main] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
    546000 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    5137900 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    6477700 nanoseconds spent executing 3 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    35687800 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 30 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 pre-partial-flushes;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}

I've set log_statement = 'all' and log_duration = on in the postgre.conf file, and when I check the logs, I see that the insert statements are being executed one by one instead of in batches.
2024-06-08 23:37:53.371 KST [11932] LOG:  execute S_2: insert into bacnet (device_id,object_id,object_type,id) values ($1,$2,$3,$4)
2024-06-08 23:37:53.371 KST [11932] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '22', $2 = '22', $3 = '22', $4 = 'd5bbd137-368a-4c51-aef8-d77c8c7251ce'
2024-06-08 23:37:53.371 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.041 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.371 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.002 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.371 KST [11932] LOG:  execute S_2: insert into bacnet (device_id,object_id,object_type,id) values ($1,$2,$3,$4)
2024-06-08 23:37:53.371 KST [11932] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '23', $2 = '23', $3 = '23', $4 = '90771e48-5bc2-4b3b-8c80-ca3e8ae63fc6'
2024-06-08 23:37:53.371 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.039 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.371 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.002 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.371 KST [11932] LOG:  execute S_2: insert into bacnet (device_id,object_id,object_type,id) values ($1,$2,$3,$4)
2024-06-08 23:37:53.371 KST [11932] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '24', $2 = '24', $3 = '24', $4 = '4ed99923-9666-4e3a-983b-b8b4486572bd'
2024-06-08 23:37:53.371 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.042 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.371 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.002 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  execute S_2: insert into bacnet (device_id,object_id,object_type,id) values ($1,$2,$3,$4)
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '25', $2 = '25', $3 = '25', $4 = 'caed3524-7d77-41ef-a9e4-614e2b629620'
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.048 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.002 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  execute S_2: insert into bacnet (device_id,object_id,object_type,id) values ($1,$2,$3,$4)
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '26', $2 = '26', $3 = '26', $4 = 'd9ee937e-437b-45aa-a258-1feba3c157b8'
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.046 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.003 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  execute S_2: insert into bacnet (device_id,object_id,object_type,id) values ($1,$2,$3,$4)
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '27', $2 = '27', $3 = '27', $4 = 'fd9d969e-a4e0-434e-9648-a377e8a276e8'
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.043 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.002 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  execute S_2: insert into bacnet (device_id,object_id,object_type,id) values ($1,$2,$3,$4)
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '28', $2 = '28', $3 = '28', $4 = 'b8ec0431-1cde-42f8-8b2c-915fde9a1c3b'
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.041 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.003 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  execute S_2: insert into bacnet (device_id,object_id,object_type,id) values ($1,$2,$3,$4)
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '29', $2 = '29', $3 = '29', $4 = 'bd81419f-8c85-4ce0-89e9-eda534ec15ef'
2024-06-08 23:37:53.372 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.042 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.375 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.019 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.375 KST [11932] LOG:  duration: 0.011 ms
2024-06-08 23:37:53.375 KST [11932] LOG:  execute S_3: COMMIT

I want to find a way to perform batch inserts with PostgreSQL. I need to check if there's an issue with the code I've written.

Your code creates a prepared statement S_2 and that one is executed 10 times, with different parameters. That's pretty fast and could be how batches are implemented in this library. It's not as fast as COPY, but much better than single inserts. See also https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-write-into-a-database-using-rewritebatchedinserts-parameter_597796

It would be helpful if you actually stated what issue you are having as the logs show the INSERTs working.

@이상찬 connection property names are case sensitive, you need to use reWriteBatchedInserts instead of rewriteBatchedInserts

@Andrey B. Panfilov Oh! It was indeed a typo issue. After fixing it as you suggested, everything worked fine. Thank you so much!!  I'm happy now.
